# Complex analysis meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum\limits_0^\infty a_nz^n$ be a power series which converges in $\mathbb{C}$ to a nowhere vanishing function $f(z)$.

a) Show that for any given $R>0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $m>N$ the polynomial $f_m(z)=\sum\limits_0^m a_nz^n$ has no zeros in $D(0;R)$.

b) True or false: $f$ extends to a meromorphic function on the extended complex plane if and only if it is constant.

I showed the first part but I cannot decide whether the statement in part b) is true or false. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: only polynomials extend as required, but polynomials have zeroes unless constant so b is true

Comment: Hint: $f(z)$ is meromorphic at infinity if $f(1/z)$ has a pole at $z = 0$.